# How to handle sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: requests that are no longer relevant when user changes screens

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5

I have a series of ViewControllers that are being pushed into a UINavigationController in a given order.  The last ViewController is simply a controller that is basically auto suggests locations to the user.  The user is presented with a textfield which they can begin typing a location and below a tableview will populate with suggestions.  This is nothing new or ground-breaking.

The issue is within that viewcontroller I'm calling the sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: api method to fetch a list of locations that match the user's input string.  My concern is that if a given request takes awhile to complete and the user goes back down the stack by popping the current screen while the request still has not come back how should I handle this scenario?

1. I see no way to cancel the request(s) if there are currently any active
2. I notice that even if I pop the screen my completionHandler block still runs and the application does not crash and the reference to the tableview is not nil.  So can I just simply "not worry about it"?  I just don't feel this is the right way to deal with it.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

-Ralph